# Received memory warning In UITableView

Tags: objective-c

I load a table with images and scroll up and down. After a minute or so, I get a "Received memory warning" notification. After seeing this message a few times, the app crashes.

I load by scrolling position 5 images every time the user scrolls to the bottom of the table.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"aCell";
PostTable_Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

CGFloat cellHeight = (screenWidth / 16) * 10 + self.view.frame.size.height * 0.09;


cell = [[PostTable_Cell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier withParentWidth:self.view.frame.size.width withCellHeight:cellHeight withParent:self withPostArray:[postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withCurrentIndexPostArray:(int)indexPath.row];

[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];

return cell;
```

}

Edit :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"aCell";
PostTable_Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

CGFloat cellHeight = (screenWidth / 16) * 10 + self.view.frame.size.height * 0.09;

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[PostTable_Cell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier withParentWidth:self.view.frame.size.width withCellHeight:cellHeight withParent:self withPostArray:[postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withCurrentIndexPostArray:(int)indexPath.row];
    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}
else
{
    [cell reloadCellContetWithParent:self withPostArray:[postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withCurrentIndexPostArray:(int)indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
 }
```

Edit 3 :

```
@implementation PostTable_Cell

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
// Initialization code
}

  - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
 }

 -(void)dealloc
 {
 #ifdef DEBUG
NSLog(@"%@ destoyed",NSStringFromClass([self class]));
 #endif
 }

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier withParentWidth:(CGFloat)parentWidth withCellHeight:(CGFloat)celltHeight  withParent:(id)parent withPostArray:(id)postArray withCurrentIndexPostArray:(int)IndexNumber
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self)
{
    mainDalegate = (Main*)parent;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    Post *curPost = (Post*)postArray;

    postId =  [curPost getPostId];
    postText =  [curPost getPostText];
    postImageUrl =  [curPost getImageUrl];
    commentsCount = [curPost getCommentsCount];
    likesCount = [curPost getLikesCount];
    likeByMe = [curPost getLikeByMe];
    facebookId = [curPost getCreatorFacebookId];
    publisherName =[curPost getCreatorName];
    currentIndexPostArray = IndexNumber;

    [GeneralMethods setNew_width:parentWidth ToView:self];
    [GeneralMethods setNew_height:celltHeight ToView:self];

    [self cellBuilderForPost];
}

return self;
 }
```

Comment: It's obvious that your images doesn't get released. You need to show some code for anyone to be able to help you. Specifically your "cellForRowAtIndexPath" would be of help

Comment: are you loading all your table at once?

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: @RoeiNadam why do you `dequeue` the cell and then `init` it again? It is not recommended to init a cell every time. If you have to run code when cell is drawn, create a custom function and run it.

Comment: I edit the question , Now the scroll in table is very slowly.

Comment: @RoeiNadam does it still gives you a warning? Also what does `reloadCellContetWithParent` do? One trick that in those scenarios is add this:  `-(void)dealloc{

#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"%@ destoyed",NSStringFromClass([self class]));
#endif
}`

Comment: Received memory warning not show , reloadCellContetWithParent load current image.

Comment: where I put this dealloc ?

Comment: @RoeiNadam use the code i provided above and check if the cells are correctly `dealloc `. Put it in the `PostTable_Cell.m`.

Comment: dealloc not called , I miss something ?

Comment: @RoeiNadam  it should be. In my apps every time `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ` is called the cell is `dealloc `. Something must be keeping your cell "alive".

Comment: Your cells are probably in retain cycles. Post your PostTable_Cell.m

Comment: I edit the question : "Edit 3"

Comment: @RoeiNadam what does `[self cellBuilderForPost];` do? Also i think that `mainDalegate` should be a weak property.

Comment: @rob180, the cell won't be deallocated if it reused, so actually the logging the dealloc would work here too efficiently.

Comment: Your code is pretty messy, with multiple method calls to global methods/other methods that is unclear what they are doing. Somewhere you have made a strong pointer to your cells in these methods. Try removing different parts of the code until the dealloc-method is called. It seems as if every cell is also handing some url's. Maybe you are making HTTP-requests from within each cell? This can cause retain cycles.

Comment: [self cellBuilderForPost] build the content of the cell , get url and download image from url with SDWebImageManager , mainDalegate is instance of my view controler Parent.

Comment: You'd probably need to upload your project somewhere for anyone to help you solve this.

Comment: comment `[self cellBuilderForPost];` and check if the cell are `dealloc `. That way you can isolate the problem.

Comment: dealloc still not call.

Comment: I don't think dealloc should get called when you scroll because it is being reused. Shouldn't it get called when tableview get deallocated?

Answer (score 0):

`mainDalegate = (Main*)parent;`
It looks like this might be your issue. Your cells are not getting released because you are creating a retain cycle.
[rules to avoid retain cycles](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html).
[image]